# Wrong UIRefreshControl behaviour when UINavigationBar.prefersLargeTitles is on

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uirefreshcontrol

[iOS 12] The `UIRefreshControl`'s indicator doesn't work as expected when I "pull to refresh" using large titles in the navigation bar.

How can I have the right `UIRefreshControl`'s indicator behaviour and using large titles? Am I missing something?

(Related https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97713)

---

#### With **`self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`**:

[image]

---

#### With **`self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `tableView.tableHeaderView = refreshControl` or `tableView.addSubView(refreshControl)` you should use `tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl`

Comment: That's right. I was doing `tableView.addSubView(refreshControl)` 